# Determining if metric space is complete

Tags: metric-spaces

Is this subset a complete metric space with the $\rho_{\infty}$ metric?

$\{f \in C[a,b] | f(a)=0\}$

I know that I must show that a Cauchy sequence has a limit in the same metric space, but I don't know how to do this. Also, what is the significance of metric choice here?

Comment: What is the $\rho_\infty$ metric?

Comment: Supremum norm $\rho_{\infty}(f,g)=||f-g||_{\infty}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

1. That uniform convergence preserves continuity, i.e. that if a sequence of continuous function $f_n$ converges pointwise and *uniformly* to $f$, then $f$ is continuous.
2. That convergence in the supremem metric $\rho_\infty$ means pointwise and *uniform* convergence.

The significance of the metric is that this *only* works for the supremem metric. In the metric $$
  \rho_2(f,g) = \int_0^2 (f(x) - g(x))^2 \,dx \text{,}
$$
for example, you have that $$
  \frac{x^n}{1 + x^n} \to \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if $x > 1$} \\ \tfrac{1}{2} &\text{if $x=1$} \\0 &\text{if $x < 1$} \end{cases} \quad \text{ as $n \to \infty$}
$$

---

You start your proof with a cauchy sequence $f_n$ in your metric space.

First, you argue that $f_n(x)$ is then a cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, for every $x$. This works because the supremum metric *by definition* says that if $d(f,g) \leq \epsilon$, then $|f(x) - g(y)| < \epsilon$ *for all* $x$. Since we know that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, this proves that $f_n$ converges pointwise to some function $f$. This also shows that if $f_n(a) = 0$ for all $n$, then $f(a) = 0$ as well.

Then, we use the definition of the supremem metric again to show that this pointwise limit is *uniform* in $x$. Again, we use that $d(f,g) \leq \epsilon$ means $|f(x) - g(y)| < \epsilon$ *for all* $x$.

We thus know that $f$ is continuous, since $f$ is the uniform limit of continuous functions, and that completes the proof.

Comment: You don't need pointwise convergence in the first statement.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the setup for uniform convergence? I'm confused how a and f(a) ties into this, and what converges to them.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy I wrote *pointwise* there just to emphasize that uniform convergence is a special case of pointwise convergence. It doesn't add any new requirement, just makes it clear that uniform convergence means pointwise convergence *and* that the pointwise limit is uniform in $x$ (or whatever you call the independent variant).

Comment: @kiwifruit I've added a more detailed explanation. Clearer now?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if a sequence of continuous functions converges is the sense $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ ($\rho_\infty$ in your notations), then it converges pointwise.

*Further details.*

1) $C[a,b]$ with metric $\rho_\infty$ is a complete space. This is covered in all books.

2) If a sequence of functions converges uniformly (i.e. in the metric $\rho_\infty$), then it converges pointwise. Follows from the definition of this metric.

3) Suppose we have a Cauchy sequence $\{f_n\}$ of functions in $L\subset C[a,b] $. Then $f_n$ converges in $C[a,b]$ by (1). By (2) we obtain pointwise convergence of $f_n$, in particular, the sequence $f_n(a)$ converges. Clearly, this sequence is identically zero, therefore the limiting function $f$ also belongs to $L$.

Comment: Well, I am confused because I don't know what to take for the terms of the Cauchy sequence. If a is only one point, should I include it as a Cauchy term, or something else?